# webscraping logins with javscript and ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, authentication, scrapy-splash

i'm stuck trying to get viewstate data to pass for form authentication. heres my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest, SplashFormRequest

class BrpSplashSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'brp_splash'
    allowed_domains = ['brp.secure.force.com']
   # start_urls = ['http://brp.secure.force.com/']     

    script = '''
        function main(splash, args)
        url = args.url
        assert(splash:go(url))
        assert(splash:wait(1))
        return splash:html() 
        end
    '''
    def start_requests(self):
        yield SplashRequest(
            url='https://brp.secure.force.com/login',
            endpoint = 'execute',
            args = {
                'lua_source':self.script
            },
            callback=self.parse
        )

    def parse(self,response):
    yield SplashFormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formxpath='//form',
        formdata={
            'AJAXREQUEST' : '_viewRoot'
            'j_id0:j_id5' : 'j_id0:j_id5'
            'j_id0:j_id5:Login1_Dealer_No': '******'
            'j_id0:j_id5:Login1_UserName': '******'
            'j_id0:j_id5:Login1_Password': '*********'
            'j_id0:j_id5:j_id26': 'en'
            'com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewState': 
        }
    )
    pass
```

inspecting the webpage and looking at the form data i  can see a huge string that is the viewstate data. its not in the html. where is it and how do i reference it?

thanks for looking,

jim

Answer (score 0):

the object i'm looking for is in the login page. i was looking for it after logging in. newbie learning curve mistake